# How to solve single quotation issue in googlesheetAPI and C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am writing an application which will write a duration e.g. (8:00:00.000 or 7:00:00.000 ) type data in a google sheet. I am writing a Timestamp type value from C# into spreadsheet's duration type cell.
The function is

```
public UpdateValuesResponse WriteToSheet(string sheetCellNumber, TimeSpan valueToWrite)
{
    try
    {
        var range = _sheetName + "!" + sheetCellNumber; // "Basic!B111";
        var valueRange = new ValueRange { MajorDimension = "COLUMNS" };

        var objectList = new List<object> { valueToWrite };
        valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { objectList };

        var update = _service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, _sheetId, range);
        update.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW;
        return update.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        throw new Exception("Error in writting data");
    }            
}
```

In spreadsheet, it is written as '8:00:00 (a **single quote** in front of the Timespan data). 
I want to write a data of google spreadsheet's duration type. How can I do this with C#? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the **ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW** to 
**ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED**